# How to pass array object from model to another controller?

Tags: codeigniter

This is a Noob question , but i have searched a lot with no luck.

I am returning array of objects from model to controller and i have to pass it to another model. I will have to convert it but how ?

This is my controller :

```
        $data['customer_phoneno'] = $this->session->userdata('customer_phoneno');
        $data['cid']=$this->Stylish_wizard->getCid($this->session->userdata('customer_phoneno'));
        $data['bookings']=$this->Myaccount_customer->getBookings($cid);
```

Model :

```
public function getBookings($cid)

    {
      $this->db->where('cid', $cid);    
      $this->db->from('bookings');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
    }
```

I  want to get the data from one model and use it to get some other data from another model.

I had tried passing $data['cid'] but got this error

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 662

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\style\application\models\Myaccount_customer.php
Line: 24
Function: where

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\style\application\controllers\Myaccount.php
Line: 95
Function: getBookings

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\style\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `cid` = `Array`

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/style/application/models/Myaccount_customer.php

Line Number: 26
```

I tried passing

```
$data['cid']->cid
```

But its not working 
When i printed $data['cid'] i got

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cid] => 8 ) )
```

So how do i convert it in string  ?

Comment: What you mean by another controller

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve

Comment: I  want to get the data from one model and use it to get some other data from another model.

Comment: you just want to pass value that returned from another model?you did right way `$this->Myaccount_customer->getBookings($cid);` but where this $cid comes from where you stored return data at `$data['cid']`.This should be `$this->Myaccount_customer->getBookings($data['cid']);`

Comment: Still not working i have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can achieve it using as

**Controller**

```
public function your_function(){
    $this->load->model('folder_name/my_calling_model');//initialize that model


//your rest code
    $data['my_data'] = $this->my_calling_model->my_calling_function();//your function to be called
}
```

You can call another model within your code as like above code,but it seems you might be having a *typo* within your code while passing `$cid` it seems to be `$data['cid']` instead. So your code looks like

```
$data['bookings']=$this->Myaccount_customer->getBookings($data['cid']);//<----- changed from $cid to $data['cid']
```

Comment: very confusing !!!two upvote with wrong answer.Even answer deos not explain anything .bellow answer is right but no up-vote.

Comment: My bad @shaifullslam but I didn't notice that one I've just given an example of how you can use another model within another controller but I'll update my answer

Comment: Try with passing `$data['cid'][0]`

Comment: Post your array `$data['cid']`

Comment: This webpage is not available

ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Comment: `print_r($data['cid']);`

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cid] => 8 ) )

Comment: Pass as `$data['cid'][0]->cid`

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you want to achieve this:

```
$data['customer_phoneno'] = $this->session->userdata('customer_phoneno');
$data['cid']=$this->Stylish_wizard->getCid($this->session->userdata('customer_phoneno'));
$data['bookings']=$this->Myaccount_customer->getBookings($data['cid']);
```

Make sure to pass the right array / object element.

edit:
Like I said: Make sure to pass the right array or object element. `$data['cid']` contains an array. But you have to pass a String(the id). So you have to look at this array and pass the right element with your id.

Comment: You should explain why your answer is right.You just explained the clue but would be better what mistake OP did.

Comment: Try $data['cid'][0]->cid.